# How to get total number of data from multiple rows and columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get number of each entry such as count of good in whole table and other entries also. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Can you please give me a example .please...I don't have much knowledge in sql

Comment: You should change your table structure to (item_id, op_id, score), then SELECT statement becomes very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` to return 1 for good, 0 for other values. Sum each for each column, add those sum's together.

```
select SUM(case when op1 = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) +
       SUM(case when op2 = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) +
       SUM(case when op3 = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) +
       SUM(case when op4 = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) +
       SUM(case when op5 = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) +
       SUM(case when op6 = 'good' then 1 else 0 end)
from tablename
```

Alternatively:

```
select op, count(*)
from
(
select op1 as op from tablename
union all
select op2 from tablename
union all
select op3 from tablename
union all
select op4 from tablename
union all
select op5 from tablename
union all
select op6 from tablename
) as t
group by op
```

Comment: Well thank you so much for your time and effort.Can you please show me how can be display the variable in php.Am getting something resource #41

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that. (I don't know php.)

Comment: No issue.Thank you so much